# Parameters never received on POST request from JQuery to Java (JAX-RS) server

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jax-rs

In the following code I am making a request from JQuery to method "save" on a JAX-RS server, with parameter userId. This JQuery runs from a Google Chrome extension (same issue when tested from localhost).

**index.html (inside Chrome extension)**

```
<script>
    $.post('https://example.com:8082/save', { userId: 'myuser' } )
    .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

The request is received, but I always get the error message `ERROR: user not specified` (see below).

**JAX-RS Server side**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/save")
    public Response save(@FormParam("userId") String userId) {

        if(userId == null) {
            return Response.ok("ERROR: user not specified", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        }
        else {
            [...]
        }
   }
```

I have tested the same request from CURL and it works well.

```
curl --data "userId=myuser" https://example.com:8082/save
```

**Chrome Debug**

```
Request URL:https://example.com:8082/save
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:131.224.32.213:8082

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myteam.slack.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 25
Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2016 17:33:05 GMT
Connection: close

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en,es;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:16
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:example.com:8082
Origin:https://myteam.slack.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36

userId=myuser
```

**EDIT:** Is it possible that it could be caused by a CORS rule? I am getting the POST request normally but no parameters. These are my filters on Tomcat. Do I need any CORS statements on JAX-RS?

**Tomcat8 conf/web.xml**

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Look in your browser dev tools. Whats the body look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving parameters using JAX-RS and jquery .ajax()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275318/retrieving-parameters-using-jax-rs-and-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I have added the "@Consumes" as specified in your link, but I get the same error. I updated my question with further info

Comment: @peeskillet just updated my question with chrome body

Comment: Look at the body. It's not valid. It should an equals sign, not a colon

Comment: @peeskillet when I click on "view source" on Chrome debug it is shown as "userId=myuser". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Could you try the same with @QueryParam? It shouldn't be the case, but since you send to specific headers Jersey may misbehave.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I just tried that and I get the same error. I used a new AJAX request and again the same error. Requests are being received but for some reason the parameter is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with an XMLHttpRequest instead. Probably inserting the content-type header made the difference? This is the working code:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://example.com:8082/save";
var params = "userId=myuser";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: jQuery is supposed to default to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"